# Why did Dumbledore have Harry stick his arm out when Barty Crouch Jr. was revealed?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, harry-potter, the-goblet-of-fire

In the scene where Barty Crouch Jr. is revealed (movie, not books) to have been impersonating Mad-Eye Moody, Barty makes a weird remark:

> I'll show you mine if you show me yours.

He then sticks his arm out to show the Dark Mark. Dumbledore then reacts by having Harry stick his arm out, which shows the injury from the potion that resurrected Voldemort.

Why did Dumbledore have Harry stick his arm out? It doesn't make sense with the rest of the conversation, nor is any exposition really given.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When Barty Crouch Jr. says,

> I'll show you mine if you show me yours.

he wasn't referring to the dark mark, but to the wound Harry got at the graveyard. He was trying to let on that they got Harry's blood and after that, he would have revealed his dark mark.

When he says this, Dumbledore got curious and checked Harry's arm to see if it got the dark mark, but it wasn't there except for that wound. Dumbledore only sticks out Harry's arm to see this. If you see, he made a dreadful face as he realized that Voldemort has returned.

> **Barty:** You know what this means, don't you? He's back. Lord Voldemort has returned.

[Script Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=harry-potter-and-the-goblet-of-fire)

Comment: Could Barty not have been _suggesting_ that Harry has a dark mark, just to get Dumbledore curious enough to check? That would be more consistent than your initial sentence argues: Barty implies that he and Harry have the same thing (yours and mine), and then shows his dark mark to imply that Harry also has a dark mark. The order of operations (Barty saying "first you, then me" but then showing his mark first) may not be relevant to what Barty was trying to insinuate.

Comment: He wanted Dumbledore to check the mark, which wasn't there, in order to let him know that Voldemort has returned.

Comment: That's what I meant with my comment. That means that it's not an inconsistency in the action and dialogue, in the sense that Barty full well knew what he was doing and he did so intentionally. Your initial phrase makes it seems like it's a movie continuity error (discrepancy between the script and the screenplay), but that doesn't seem to be the case when you consider Barty's intentions.

Comment: When I first started writing the answer, I thought it was an inconsistency. But I later realized it wasn't and didn't remove it then. I have edited my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you can say he was putting on a ruse to make Dumbledore check if Harry had a Dark Mark. Dumbledore would have no reason to think that was even possible. But he clearly did understand the significance of Harry's wound ("you know what this means, don't you?"), so no ruse was necessary; Crouch wanted Dumbledore to check for such a wound.

Comment: "*Dumbledore got curious and checked Harry's arm to see if it got the dark mark*" - this is not only baseless speculation but seems completely implausible. Why on earth would *Harry* have the Dark Mark, a badge to mark out Voldemort's most trusted followers?

Answer (score 17):

I took that scene as Crouch wanting to prove to Dumbledore that Voldemort is back, by showing his Dark Mark burning on his arm, which hadn't happened since Voldermort had disappeared all those years ago.

He knew that Harry was being taken to give blood to contribute to the resurrection, and was effectively backing up his claim to Dumbledore that the plot had succeeded by getting Harry to show where he had been cut for the blood (which Dumbledore could have been expected to know would be a part of such a resurrection ritual).

Getting Dumbledore to verify that Harry had indeed lost blood, combined with the Dark Mark burning simply serves to reinforce the truth Barty is telling, that Voldemort is back, in case Dumbledore might have disregarded the rantings of a clearly crazy person, or not believed what Harry had to say on the matter.  The wizarding community is shown to have a slight unwillingness to believe stuff they don't like the sound of.

**TL;DR:** Barty's trying to provide evidence to show Dumbledore beyond a shadow of a doubt that Voldemort has returned.